# Suspension not bouncy raleigh activator 2

Tags: full-suspension

Hi i got a preowned raleigh activator 2 with front suspension and rear tube dampening system but the front and back suspensions dont seem as bouncy as i thought is there a way to get them to do their job properly.i am 10stone in weight and height 5,10 if its to do with the weight.

Comment: It looks like the Raleigh Activator 2 is about a 20 year old model -- the suspension is probably shot after all these years. You'd either have to find a way to rebuild/replace it or get a new bike.

Comment: Suspension 20 years ago was a very different animal to today. If its moving, its working as designed.